# Is there a standard way to obtain an approximation piecewise-linear function for a function

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

I am trying to find a generic way to get an approximation function for a given function. 
(I will be doing it programmatically eventually). What I want to obtain is a set of pairs, mapping the x-axis to the function's value, through which the approximation function can be interpolated as a piece-wise linear function later on.

My issue is that I don't know how frequent or sparse these points need to be on the x-axis. Obviously every function has its own behaviour, and what suits one does not suit the other. Also, it makes more sense for these intervals to vary dynamically to reflect the activity of the function at that region. I am thinking of maybe having some kind of error-tolerance value which defines how much the approximate function can deviate from the real one.

Is there some numeric or iterative method to obtain the values for a given function $f(x)$ that can build an approximation function $g(x)$?

Comment: It's no good idea to call your approximating function $f'$ because you will certainly need to use the derivative $f'$ of $f$ t estimate the error :)

Comment: Fair enough, changed to $g(x)$ :). Any idea how do I go about this, or from where do I start looking?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Some generic ideas are [least squares approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), [minimax approximation using the Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm), and [Gal's accurate table method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal%27s_accurate_tables).

Comment: @njuffa Not sure what's unclear. If I have a function $f(x)$ I want a vector of pairs $(<x_0, f(x_0)>, <x_1, f(x_1)>, ... )$ that represent a piecewise-linear approximation of the curve of $f(x)$. I do not know $x_0, x_1 ... $ for each function, so discovering them is part of the algorithm I am looking for, and they will be specific for each specific function, and not at regular intervals. I do not want a polynomial approximation though, just a piecewise-linear one.

Comment: linear = polynomial of degree 1.

Comment: Yes but its not what I want. I want a piecewise linear function, represented by a set of points.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I came up with a method for doing something very similar to what you are talking about if not quite the same thing. I am on mobile right now but essentially you multiply every piece by a function that is 1 on the interval that piece is on, and 0 on other places. it can get arbitrarily close. chat me for more in-depth details

Comment: @FantaC I moved forward and away from this need, but would be interested to see what solution you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as the approximation with the free-knot splines, or optimal knot distribution. Maybe start by reading a few papers: Jupp, D. L. B, "Approximation to data by splines with free knots.", SIAM J. Numer. Anal., vol 15, No 2, 1978; or  Lindstrom, Mary J., "Penalized Estimation of free-knot splines." Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, Vol . 8, No. 2, 1999.

If you have a discretized function, take a look at the methods in [Matlab Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://au.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/how-to-choose-knots.html), e.g.,

OPTKNT Optimal knot distribution.
OPTKNT(TAU,K)  returns an `optimal' knot sequence for
interpolation at data sites TAU(1), ..., TAU(n) by splines of order K.

Or a least squares fit with [Free-knot spline approximation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25872-free-knot-spline-approximation).